# Cannot Add Data Connection Visual Studio 2010

Tags: visual-studio-2010

There is an error stating that I am unable to add a data connection because it cannot load a file or assembly:

```
Microsoft.SqlServer.Managment.Sdk.Sfc, Version = 10.0.0.0, Culture = neutral, 
PublicKeyToken =89845dcd8080cc91 or one of its dependencies.

The System cannot find the file specified.
```

Any help would be great!

Answer (score 2):

You probably need to reinstall SQL server.

Here's some links:

http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=123721&clcid=0x409

http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=123708&clcid=0x409

http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=123717&clcid=0x409